# Anaconda jupyter notebook "connection failed" error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, jupyter

I recently installed anaconda and tried to run Jupyter Notebook. I am using Windows 10. I opened a folder and ran the notebook. Whenever I click to open a file, after a few seconds of loading the file onto a new tab, I see the following error message:
[image: Error message]

When I click "ok", I see this as well:
[image]

[image]

I have re-installed anaconda more than thrice but this problem remains. My internet connection is not an issue here as I am able to run google on other tabs.
The following is the error message on the anaconda prompt: \

```
(base) C:\Users\aayus>cd c:\MLcourse

(base) c:\MLCourse>jupyter-notebook
[W 2021-05-25 12:49:15.300 LabApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-05-25 12:49:15.301 LabApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2021-05-25 12:49:15.317 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\aayus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2021-05-25 12:49:15.317 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\aayus\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 12:49:15.322 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: c:\MLCourse
[I 12:49:15.323 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
[I 12:49:15.324 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=a24e8ab3aa1629c4892dded671be9d26b149e7492d74a1e9
[I 12:49:15.324 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=a24e8ab3aa1629c4892dded671be9d26b149e7492d74a1e9
[I 12:49:15.324 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:49:15.366 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/aayus/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-21792-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=a24e8ab3aa1629c4892dded671be9d26b149e7492d74a1e9
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=a24e8ab3aa1629c4892dded671be9d26b149e7492d74a1e9
[W 12:49:27.828 NotebookApp] Notebook ConditionalProbabilityExercise.ipynb is not trusted
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 12:49:28.339 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 4ed3dc80-f87f-41f4-9981-320da9710f87, name: python3
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)

(base) c:\MLCourse>[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
```

Can someone pls help with this? I am a fair beginner, and cannot find an answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same error after re-installing Anaconda and found the solution here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4909

I activated my troubled environment and install the followings:

- `conda install -c conda-forge pywin32`
- `conda install -c anaconda jupyter_client`
- `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_core`

Worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for me it worked with this:

```
windows >> proxy settings >> automatically detect setting >> turn off.
```